# How to export sql table,sp,view with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I want to export tables, views, sp from my database to file.

One way to do that is to backup the database - I can't use this option because the database is on remote location and I do not have access to db server filesystem.

The other way is to use "Generate and Publis Script" wizard, and choose data and schema. - Which is failed during the generation (and I don't know why, for some reason I don't care why).

So my question is there is a sql query that I can run which iterate on all tables, views, and sp and get the schema and get data and write to file? (if some table is failed to open because some reason, then ignore).

Can I do it with nodejs? using [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) perhaps? I not sure how to get table/view/sp schema with sequlize.

I would much like for guidance here

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly, you'd like to select and view a tables contents and then be able to export it into a file on your computer right ?

If that's the case, I would do as follows:

***1) First import my required functions (In my case I use MSSQL)***

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const fs = require('fs');
```

I use **MSSQL** for database managing, so in this case I would need to import MSSQL to be able to connect and query my DB.

**FS** (Or '**File System**') contains a function to copy a file from a certain file location into another location.

***2) Then I will configure my database connection:***

```
var config =
{
   user: 'your username to log in',
   password: 'password to log in',
   server: "server path",
   database: 'name of the database',
   connectionTimeout: 0,
   requestTimeout: 0,
   pool:{
         idleTimeoutMillis: 500,
         max: 1
   }
```

};

***3)Then I would start making my function which would include the querying and saving of the file:***

```
function commenceQuery()
{
   var connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
   var request = new sql.Request(connection);
   request.query("DECLARE @output removableTable (id INT IDENTITY, command NVARCHAR(512)) DECLARE @query = 'SELECT * FROM yourTable', @outputFile = VARCHAR (2048) = 'Where you want the file to be saved, most probably will be on the database computer', @connectionString VARCHAR = '-U databaseUserName -P databasePassword' + @@servername, @bcpQuery = 'bcp "@query" QUERYOUT "@outputFile" -T -c -t, -r\n @connectionString' SET @bcpQuery = REPLACE (@bcpQuery, '@query', @query) SET @bcpQuery = REPLACE (@bcpQuery, '@outputFile', @outputFile+'Test_Name.csv') SET @bcpQuery = REPLACE (@bcpQuery, '@connectionString', @connectionString) SET @bcpQuery = REPLACE (@bcpQuery, CHAR(10), ' ')) INSERT INTO @output EXEC master..xp cmdshell @bcpquery")
   .then(function()
   {
      fs.copyFile('/filePath/to/where/output/isSpecified', '/filePath/of/where/you/want/toSave')
   }
   .catch(function()
   {
      conn.close()
   })
};
```

To explain in details the query I've stated inside ***request.query('')***:

- `DECLARE @output removableTable (id INT IDENTITY, command
  NVARCHAR(512))` 
  Declares a variable like a temporary table to put the information gathered into it
- `DECLARE @query = 'SELECT * FROM yourTable'` 
  Declares a variable to hold the actual Query string
- `@outputFile = VARCHAR (2048) = 'Where you want the file to be saved,
  most probably will be on the database computer'` 
  Declares a variable to hold the file path destination of where the database should output the file, ex: C:\Program Files\anyFolder
- `@connectionString VARCHAR = '-U databaseUserName -P databasePassword' + @@servername` 
  Same as the config we used above, it is the key to logging in to the database itself.
- `@bcpQuery = 'bcp "@query" QUERYOUT "@outputFile" -T -c -t, -r\n
  @connectionString'` 
  We're going to use this as a means of execution, replacing in variable that has the '@' with the actual values (That are declared below)
- `SET @bcpQuery = REPLACE (@bcpQuery, '@query', @query)` 
  Would replace @query with the string it contains
- `SET @bcpQuery = REPLACE (@bcpQuery, '@outputFile',
  @outputFile+'Test_Name.csv')`
  Same as above
- `SET @bcpQuery = REPLACE (@bcpQuery, '@connectionString',
  @connectionString)`
  Same as above
- `SET @bcpQuery = REPLACE (@bcpQuery, CHAR(10), ' '))`
  Removes any line breaks
- `INSERT INTO @output`
  Inserts all what you received into @output
- `EXEC master..xp cmdshell @bcpquery` 
  Executes the whole query in the cmdshell

Hope this helps !! Let me know if you get stuck with something